# SQLite Count where query

Tags: android, sqlite, select, count, where-clause

I use a simple sql lite query to fetch the count value from a table.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(name2) FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   return cursor.getInt(0);
}
return cursor.getInt(0);
```

This works good

But when I add a where clause to the select query

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(name2) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE name in (" + k + ")", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   return cursor.getInt(0);
}
return cursor.getInt(0);
```

process stops unexpectedly.......

Comment: Also, please post the stacktrace from `logcat`.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a space in front of the `WHERE`: `... + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE name ...`

But there's a lot wrong with your code:

- Why do you use `rawQuery()` when there's nice methods like [`query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that spare you from building query strings at risk of SQL injection? Even `rawQuery()` takes query arguments as second parameter.
- Where do you close your `Cursor`? You'll leak memory this way.
- What happens if `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns `false` and you execute the line after your `if`-block? This will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of that k variable, it might be not valid for sql IN operator.